# What term captures "just the thing" or "exactly what is needed"?

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Example usage:

> If Plato and Aristotle wish to maintain the status quo, then such a system is **just the thing** that is needed.

"Sufficient" doesn't carry it. "Ideal" gets closer. What word captures "just the thing" or "exactly what is needed"?

Comment: _Optimum_ Latin for 'the best possible'.

Comment: *Optimum* is a great word—I forgot about that one. *Optimal* may actually work well in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Reminds me of [The Story of Mel, a Real Programmer](http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/mel.html), in which the phrase "most pessimum" occurs.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Great story. Love that loop code.

Comment: If X is the desired outcome,then Y is *precisely* the thing called for.

Answer (score 2):

***Very thing*** is the very thing for you.

> Exactly what is needed or wanted, as in *That hat's the very thing to complete the costume.* This idiom, which uses very to denote exact identity, was first recorded in 1768.
>
> <sup>http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/very+thing,+the</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to accept a phrase, consider the idiom "That's the ticket!"

Comment: I wish I could use this on my academic paper, but this is awesome for informal writing! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If it is a high register I would consider using *ad hoc*. It's cult, but I don't think it to be strictly formal, though - it seems to refer to a solution *purposely* intended for the problem, rather than an optimal solution found at random.

*Grammar tip: in English it works as an adjective - **that is the ad hoc system**.*